# Navigation with megamenu in SharePoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, 2016, css

I successfully created a mock-up navigation menu with a mega menu item (Directorate) in [codepen](https://codepen.io/isogunro/pen/a40601ea4d76de8fac6ff1fe6267d3dc), but it isn't working as I would hope.

When I try to implement it in my SharePoint site, this is what I get (screenshot attached):
[image]

Any ideas why?

Here's the code:

```
var cacheNavData = [];
var cacheSubNavData = [];
var cacheMegaMenuData = [];
var cacheCategoryMenuData = [];

$(document).ready(function(){
 getData("Training Navigation").done(function(data1){
    cacheNavData = data1.d.results;
    getData("Sub Navigation").done(function(data2){
        cacheSubNavData = data2.d.results;
        getData("Mega Menu Category").done(function(data3){
            cacheMegaMenuData = data3.d.results;
            getData("category menu").done(function(data4){
                cacheCategoryMenuData = data4.d.results;
                megaMenu();
                createNavigation(cacheNavData);

                });
            });
        });
    });
})

function getData(lName){    

        if (lName != "Sub Navigation") {    
            var endPointUrl = "/otg/_api/web/lists/getbyTitle('" + lName + "')/items";
        }else {
            var endPointUrl ="/otg/_api/web/lists/getbyTitle('" + lName + "')/items?$select=parentNav/URL, parentNav/URLNAME,subLink&$expand=parentNav";
        }

        return $.ajax({
            url: endPointUrl,
            type: "GET",
            headers: {
                        "accept":"application/json;odata=verbose"
            }
        }); 
}


    function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
        if (x.className === "topnav") {
            x.className += " responsive";
        } else {
            x.className = "topnav";
        }
    }

    function createNavigation(navData) {
        var topNav = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
        for (var x = 0; x < navData.length; x++) {

            if (navData[x].dropDown === "no") {
                var aLink = _createEl("a");
                var aTextNode = document.createTextNode(navData[x].URLNAME);
                aLink.href = navData[x].URL;
                aLink.appendChild(aTextNode);
                topNav.appendChild(aLink);
            } else if (navData[x].dropDown === "yes") {                 
                buildSubNavigation = buildSubNavBar(navData[x].URLNAME);
                topNav.appendChild(buildSubNavigation);
            } 
        }
    }

    function buildSubNavBar(subNavID, isDirectorate) {
        //create div and add dropdown class
        var ddDiv = _createEl("div");
            ddDiv.classList.add("dropdown");

        //create button and add text
        var btn = _createEl("button");
            btn.classList.add("dropbtn");

       // var btnText = document.createTextNode(subNavID);
        var btnText = document.createTextNode(subNavID);
        //append the text to the button
        btn.appendChild(btnText);

        //create i tag and add "fa fa-caret-down" classes
        var itag = _createEl("i");
        itag.classList.add("fa");
        itag.classList.add("fa-caret-down");
        btn.appendChild(itag);
        ddDiv.appendChild(btn);

        var ddContent = _createEl("div");
        ddContent.classList.add("dropdown-content");
        for (var i = 0; i < cacheSubNavData.length; i++) {  
            if (cacheSubNavData[i].parentNav.URLNAME === subNavID  && cacheSubNavData[i].parentNav.id !== "Directorate") {
                var li = _createEl("li");
                var a = _createEl("a");
                var aTextNode = document.createTextNode(cacheSubNavData[i].subLink.Description);

               // a.href = cacheSubNavData[i].subURL;
                a.href = cacheSubNavData[i].subLink.Url;
                a.appendChild(aTextNode);
                ddContent.appendChild(a);  
            }
        }
        ddDiv.appendChild(ddContent);
        return ddDiv;
    }

    function _createEl(el) {
        return document.createElement(el);
    }


    function megaMenu(){
            var topNav = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
            var ddDiv = _createEl("div");
            ddDiv.classList.add("Mdropdown");

                    //create button and add text
             var btn = _createEl("button");
            btn.classList.add("Mdropbtn");

            //create div and add dropdown class
            var megaDivDropDown = _createEl("div");
            megaDivDropDown.classList.add("Mdropdown");

            var megaBtn = _createEl("button");
            megaBtn.classList.add("Mdropbtn");

            megaDivDropDown.appendChild(megaBtn)
            var megaI = _createEl("i");
            megaI.classList.add("fa");
            megaI.classList.add("fa-caret-down");

            megaBtn.appendChild(megaI);

            var megaDDivContent = _createEl("div");
            megaDDivContent.classList.add("Mdropdown-content");

            var headerDiv = _createEl("div");
            headerDiv.classList.add("Mheader");

            var megaH2 = _createEl("h2");
            var h2Text = document.createTextNode("Team Sites");

            megaH2.appendChild(h2Text);
            headerDiv.appendChild(megaH2);
            megaDDivContent.appendChild(headerDiv);

            var megaDDivRow = _createEl("div");
            megaDDivRow.classList.add("Mrow");
            for (var i = 0; i < cacheMegaMenuData.length; i++) {
            console.log("-->"+cacheMegaMenuData[i].Title);

                var megaDivCol = _createEl("div");
                megaDivCol.classList.add("Mcolumn");
                var colHr = _createEl("h3");
                var colHrText = document.createTextNode(cacheMegaMenuData[i].Title);
                colHr.appendChild(colHrText);
                megaDivCol.appendChild(colHr);
                for (var x = 0; x < cacheCategoryMenuData.length; x++) {
                console.log(cacheMegaMenuData[i].category)
                console.log(cacheCategoryMenuData[x].Title);
                    if (cacheMegaMenuData[i].Title === cacheCategoryMenuData[x].Title) {
                        var colAnchor = _createEl("a");
                        colAnchor.href = cacheCategoryMenuData[x].menuUrl;
                        var menuColText = document.createTextNode(cacheCategoryMenuData[x].menuItem);
                        colAnchor.appendChild(menuColText);     
                        megaDivCol.appendChild(colAnchor);
                        megaDDivRow.appendChild(megaDivCol);
                        megaDDivContent.appendChild(megaDDivRow);
                        ddDiv.appendChild(megaDDivContent);
                        console.log(ddDiv);
                    }
                }
            }
        topNav.appendChild(ddDiv);
        console.log(topNav)
    }
```

**CSS Code**

```
    .topnav {
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #333  !important;
    }

    .topnav a {
      float: left;
      display: block;
      color: #f2f2f2  !important;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 12px;
    }

    .active {
      background-color: #4CAF50;
      color: white  !important;
    }

    .topnav .icon {
      display: none;
    }

    .dropdown {
      float: left;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .dropdown .dropbtn {
      font-size: 12px;    
      border: none;
      outline: none;
      color: white  !important;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      background-color: #333    !important;
      font-family: inherit;
      margin: 0;
    }

    .dropdown-content {
      display: none;
      position: fixed !important;
      background-color: #f9f9f9  !important;
      min-width: 160px;
      box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2)v;
      z-index: 300 !important;
      color:black;
    }

    .dropdown-content a {
      float: none !important;
      color: black !important;
      padding: 12px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
      text-align: left;
    }

    .topnav a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
      background-color: #555  !important;
      color: white  !important;;
    }

    .dropdown-content a:hover {
      background-color: #ddd  !important;
      color: black  !important;
    }

    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
      display: block;
      color:black !important;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
      .topnav a:not(:first-child), .dropdown .dropbtn {
        display: none;
      }
      .topnav a.icon {
        float: right;
        display: block;
      }
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
      .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
      .topnav.responsive .icon {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
      }
      .topnav.responsive a {
        float: none;
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
      }
      .topnav.responsive .dropdown {float: none;}
      .topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {position: relative;}
      .topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: left;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code for your reference.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
</div>
<style>
body {margin:0;font-family:Arial}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 17px;    
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: #333;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.topnav a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child), .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown {float: none;}
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
  }
}




/*MEGA-MENU*/
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.Mnavbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.Mnavbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.Mdropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.Mdropdown .Mdropbtn {
  font-size: 17px;    
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: #333;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.Mnavbar a:hover, .Mdropdown:hover .Mdropbtn {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}

.Mdropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.Mdropdown-content .Mheader {
  background: #555;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
}

.Mdropdown:hover .Mdropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

/* Create three equal columns that floats next to each other */
.Mcolumn {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  height: 250px;
}

.Mcolumn a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.Mcolumn a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.Mrow:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* Responsive layout - makes the three columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .Mcolumn {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
}
</style>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var cacheNavData = [];
var cacheSubNavData = [];
var cacheMegaMenuData = [];
var cacheCategoryMenuData = [];

$(document).ready(function(){
    getData("Training Navigation").done(function(data1){
        cacheNavData = data1.d.results;
        getData("Sub Navigation").done(function(data2){
            cacheSubNavData = data2.d.results;
            getData("Mega Menu Category").done(function(data3){
                cacheMegaMenuData = data3.d.results;
                getData("category menu").done(function(data4){
                    cacheCategoryMenuData = data4.d.results;
                    createNavigation(cacheNavData);
                });
            });
        });
    });
})
function getData(lName){
    var endPointUrl=_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
    if (lName != "Sub Navigation") {    
        endPointUrl+= "/_api/web/lists/getbyTitle('" + lName + "')/items";
    }else {
        endPointUrl+="/_api/web/lists/getbyTitle('" + lName + "')/items?$select=parentNav/URL, parentNav/URLNAME,subLink&$expand=parentNav";
    }
    return $.ajax({
        url: endPointUrl,
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            "accept":"application/json;odata=verbose"
        }
    }); 
}
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "topnav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
    }
}

function createNavigation(navData) {
    var topNav = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    for (var x = 0; x < navData.length; x++) {
        if (navData[x].dropDown === "no") {
            var aLink = _createEl("a");
            var aTextNode = document.createTextNode(navData[x].URLNAME);
            aLink.href = navData[x].URL;
            aLink.appendChild(aTextNode);
            topNav.appendChild(aLink);
        } else if (navData[x].dropDown === "yes") {
            var buildSubNavigation;
            buildSubNavigation = buildSubNavBar(navData[x].URLNAME);
            topNav.appendChild(buildSubNavigation);
        } else {
            //build megamenu
            var buildSubNavigation;
            buildDirectorateNav = buildDirectorateMegaMenu(navData[x].URLNAME);
        }
    }
}

function buildDirectorateMegaMenu(navDataID) {
    var buildNav;
    var topNav = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    buildNav = buildSubNavBar(navDataID, "training");  //Build mega menu and attach in buildSubNavBar()
    topNav.appendChild(buildNav);
}

function buildSubNavBar(subNavID, isDirectorate) {
    //create div and add dropdown class
    var ddDiv = _createEl("div");
    if(isDirectorate === "training"){
        ddDiv.classList.add("Mdropdown");
    }else{
        ddDiv.classList.add("dropdown");
    }
    //create button and add text
    var btn = _createEl("button");
    if(isDirectorate === "training"){
        btn.classList.add("Mdropbtn");
    }else{
        btn.classList.add("dropbtn");
    }
    var btnText = document.createTextNode(subNavID);
    //append the text to the button
    btn.appendChild(btnText);

    //create i tag and add "fa fa-caret-down" classes
    var itag = _createEl("i");
    itag.classList.add("fa");
    itag.classList.add("fa-caret-down");
    btn.appendChild(itag);
    ddDiv.appendChild(btn);

    var ddContent = _createEl("div");
    ddContent.classList.add("dropdown-content");
    for (var i = 0; i < cacheSubNavData.length; i++) {
        if (cacheSubNavData[i].parentNav.URLNAME=== subNavID  && cacheSubNavData[i].parentNav.URLNAME !== "Training") {
            var li = _createEl("li");
            var a = _createEl("a");
            var aTextNode = document.createTextNode(cacheSubNavData[i].subLink.Description);

            a.href = cacheSubNavData[i].subLink.Url;
            a.appendChild(aTextNode);
            ddContent.appendChild(a);  
        }
    }

    if(isDirectorate === "training"){
        //alert("I ");
        //create div and add dropdown class
        var megaDivDropDown = _createEl("div");
        megaDivDropDown.classList.add("dropdown");

        var megaBtn = _createEl("button");
        megaBtn.classList.add("dropbtn");

        megaDivDropDown.appendChild(megaBtn);
        var megaI = _createEl("i");
        megaI.classList.add("fa");
        megaI.classList.add("fa-caret-down");

        megaBtn.appendChild(megaI);

        var megaDDivContent = _createEl("div");
        megaDDivContent.classList.add("Mdropdown-content");

        var headerDiv = _createEl("div");
        headerDiv.classList.add("Mheader");

        var megaH2 = _createEl("h2");
        var h2Text = document.createTextNode("Team Sites");

        megaH2.appendChild(h2Text);
        headerDiv.appendChild(megaH2);
        megaDDivContent.appendChild(headerDiv);

        var megaDDivRow = _createEl("div");
        megaDDivRow.classList.add("Mrow");

        //Loop through categories & sub-categories items
        for (var i = 0; i < cacheMegaMenuData.length; i++) {
            var megaDivCol = _createEl("div");
            megaDivCol.classList.add("Mcolumn");
            var colHr = _createEl("h3");
            var colHrText = document.createTextNode(cacheMegaMenuData[i].category);
            colHr.appendChild(colHrText);
            megaDivCol.appendChild(colHr);
            for (var x = 0; x < cacheCategoryMenuData.length; x++) {
                if (cacheMegaMenuData[i].category === cacheCategoryMenuData[x].category) {
                    var colAnchor = _createEl("a");
                    colAnchor.href = cacheCategoryMenuData[x].menuUrl;
                    var menuColText = document.createTextNode(cacheCategoryMenuData[x].menuItem);
                    colAnchor.appendChild(menuColText);

                    megaDivCol.appendChild(colAnchor);
                    megaDDivRow.appendChild(megaDivCol);
                    megaDDivContent.appendChild(megaDDivRow);
                    ddDiv.appendChild(megaDDivContent);
                }
            }
            //create the other stuff
            //console.log(megaDivCol)
            console.log("megaDdivRow:");
            console.log(ddDiv);
        }
    }
    ddDiv.appendChild(ddContent);
    return ddDiv;
}    
function _createEl(el) {
    return document.createElement(el);
}
</script>
```

The list design and result in screenshot below.
[image]

Comment: Hi LZ_MSFT, what's the details of the 'Sub Navigation'?  Are subLink and parentNav lookups into Training Navigation?  I get the following error: /_api/web/lists/getbyTitle('Sub%20Navigation')/items?$select=parentNav/URL,%20parentNav/URLNAME,subLink&$expand=parentNav 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: This is what I have 'Sub Navigation Settings':  https://pasteboard.co/IV8J6ro.png  subLink Column: https://pasteboard.co/IV8JNos.png  parentNav column settings: https://pasteboard.co/IV8L1WB.png

Comment: The "subLink" is a hyperlink field, and the "parentNav" is a lookup field from the "Training Navigation" list.

Comment: I still get an error..any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: nevermind, I was able to figure it out.  When I created the URLNAME column, SP changed the internal name to something else.  Thank you so much for your help.  You always come to my rescue when I really need it.  Much appreciated!